# An <img> element in a Stack Overflow post with width before src doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting

This HTML, with the `src` attribute before `width`, works when posting on Stack Overflow:

```
<img src="https://www.codeplex.com/Images/codeplex.png" width="150" />
```

This doesn't work:

```
<img width="150" src="https://www.codeplex.com/Images/codeplex.png" />
```

I don't see any reason for the fixed order. Is it a bug?

Comment: I've been a member of this site for, what, six years now and I didn't know this was possible in the first place!

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: Well, it just doesn't work. :D I can't see the `<img>` element in the source code, the site ignores the full element.

Comment: What kind of madman are you? Trying to specify `src` after `width`...

Comment: Please, if you can, [do not hotlink any images](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1256/2336) (see `A` paragraph there), but create duplicates instead and post them at Imgur via built-in editor feature (& give the source).

Comment: Note: once you have uploaded a picture using the built-in button in the editor you are able to change its size. For example if the picture is at `XXXXX.png` you can use `XXXXXm.png` for a "medium" image and `XXXXXs.png` for a "small" image.

Comment: You need at least 10 reputation to post images.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is entirely by design. While it's not called out in the [official documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images), the [relevant Community FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/226203) points out that

> **The attribute order is important!** Using a different order (e.g., `height` before `width`) will strip the tag!

Comment: Ok, but why? I can't udertand why the order matters. Faster parsing?

Comment: AFAIK, the parsing's regex-based, or at least was when the site started. to keep from [releasing Zalgo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2474859), the regex was basically made to only understand a very limited subset of HTML, and throw out more or less anything malformed. So some combination of faster parsing and simpler code (regex vs. html-parsing library) was gained, in exchange for a narrow case (using HTML code instead of markdown to get width and height control) being picky. I may be remembering wrongly, though.

Comment: So, seems like a feature-request for making it less confusingly pedantic would be in order. Whether it also will be implemented...

Comment: @BillyMailman - ha! Even at the [so] they parse HTML with regex!

Comment: While we're at it, can we make unrecognised tags auto-escaped, rather than disappear into a black hole? Many [tag:xml] and [tag:html] posts just appear blank until edited because the parser swallows all the code...

Comment: Or, if this is not going to change, at least update the official documentation to mention this.

Comment: Full specification from [source](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Sanitizer.js): `var img_white = /^(<img\ssrc="(https?:\/\/|\/)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)*[\]$]+"(\swidth="\d{1,3}")?(\sheight="\d{1,3}")?(\salt="[^"<>]*")?(\stitle="[^"<>]*")?\s?\/?>)$/i;` The difference between SO's code and the regex code to deal with HTML on the wild is that they don't try to balance tags, and the regex are strictly specified to allow a restricted subset of HTML.